# Web Api Endpoint inside Docker Container is not called

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Hi I have placed a web api inside the Docker Container.

The application is running successfully inside the Docker. The swagger page is rendered successfully.

But when I execute a particular endpoint. It throws Null exception error or in some case it is giving no response.

The application is running successful when I run it through IIS express and endpoints are working fine.

Help me on how to identify the issue.

[image]

Error :

```
Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:50352/SecretServer/api/v1/secrets/3181

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]

Executing endpoint 'IO.Swagger.Controllers.SecretsApiController.SecretsServiceGetSecret (IO.Swagger)'

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[3]

Route matched with {action = "SecretsServiceGetSecret", controller = "SecretsApi"}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult SecretsServiceGetSecret(System.Nullable`1[System.Int32], System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]) on controller IO.Swagger.Controllers.SecretsApiController (IO.Swagger).

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[2]

Executed action IO.Swagger.Controllers.SecretsApiController.SecretsServiceGetSecret (IO.Swagger) in 27.1938ms

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]

Executed endpoint 'IO.Swagger.Controllers.SecretsApiController.SecretsServiceGetSecret (IO.Swagger)'

fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]

Connection id "0HM3CUKDJTLD2", Request id "0HM3CUKDJTLD2:00000003": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

at IO.Swagger.Operations.DataConversion.Converts(SecretModelLatest secret) in C:\app\Operations\DataConversion.cs:line 18

at IO.Swagger.Controllers.SecretsApiController.SecretsServiceGetSecret(Nullable`1 id, Nullable`1 includeInactive) in C:\app\Controllers\SecretsApi.cs:line 538

at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )

at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)

at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)

at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

Comment: It sounds like an error in your application code. Does any of you code depend on being run in windows? e.g. dependin on specific IIS certs? What is null?

Comment: @Shane I don't think we are using any certs. Need to verify it also. Thanks for your hint.

Comment: Whatever is at "C:\app\Operations\DataConversion.cs:line 18" will bring you a step further :)